# How to hide module in mobile view only in Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am designing website with Joomla.
Now I want to hide a module on mobile view only.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please share some more information. What framework is your template using? Are you using Bootstrap? If so, what version?

Comment: I am using t3-framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap Template, and there is an option for Module Class Suffix in Module, then you can add class

```
<space>hidden-phone for Bootstrap 2
<space>hidden-xs for Bootstrap 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Most frameworks have built-in responsive classes. These are classes that can be added to any module (using [Module Class Suffix](https://docs.joomla.org/Module_Class_Suffix)) in order to control on what screen sizes the module is visible.

**For T3 framework, use the class `.hidden-phone` to hide a module for screen sized below 768px.**

These are the classes and the corresponding screen sizes:

[image: T3 Framework mobile classes]

Read more about available [responsive classes here](http://docs.joomlabamboo.com/joomla-templates/responsive-documentation).

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution whereby you assign a custom class in the module such as 'hidden-mobile' then create a suitable media query using display:none. For example:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 787px) { 
    .hidden-mobile { 
        display:none;
        } 
    }
```